# Expected score from threshold

Tags: probability, expectation

We play a game where a sequence of $n$ numbers is drawn uniformly from $[0,1]$, and we need to set a threshold $0\leq a\leq 1$. For every number that is at least our threshold, we get $a$ points, otherwise we get nothing.

If we need to set a threshold before seeing the numbers, we will set $a=1/2$ to maximize the expected value of our score, since this expected value is $a(1-a)$. This gives expected score $n/4$, and average expected score $1/4$.

However, if we can set the threshold *after* seeing the numbers, we may set something different depending on what numbers we see. (For example, if all numbers are $1$ we will set $a=1$.)

**Question**: As $n\rightarrow\infty$, does the average expected score approach $1/4$? My intuition is that it should, because as the sequence gets longer it gets closer to random.

(I originally also asked for the expected value for any $n$, but I think that is less interesting.)

**Update**: zhoraster has provided an answer using a formula involving Brownian bridge. What about this [slightly modified version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867465/expected-score-from-threshold-with-number-deletions), where such formula doesn't seem to apply?

Comment: Clearly for $n=1$ the expected score and average expected score is $\dfrac{1}{2}$.  For $n=2$ I think the expected score is $\displaystyle  2 \int_0^1\int_{x/2}^x 2y \,dy \,dx +2 \int_0^1\int_0^{x/2} x \,dy \,dx  =\dfrac56$ and average expected score is $\dfrac{5}{12}$. Simulation suggests that for $n=100$ the expected score may be about $26.4$ and the average expected score about $0.264$

Comment: Deleted my incorrect answer, thanks all for pointing out the error :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The average does approach $1/4$, moreover, the rate of convergence is $O(1/\sqrt{n})$ (and the constant can be estimated).

Indeed, let $U_1,\dots,U_n$ be the numbers. We are interested in 
$$
M_n  = \frac1n \mathsf E\left[\max_{t\in[0,1]} t\cdot \#\{k: U_k\ge t\} \right]  = \mathsf E\left[\max_{t\in[0,1]} t\cdot \left(1-\frac1n\cdot \#\{k: U_k< t\} \right)\right]\\ 
= \mathsf E\left[\max_{t\in[0,1]} t\cdot \left(1- \hat F_n(t) \right)\right],
$$
where $\hat{F}_n(t) = \frac1n\cdot \#\{k: U_k< t\}$ is the (Russian-style) empirical cdf of the sample $U_1,\dots, U_k$. In particular,
$$
M_n\ge \mathsf E\left[\frac12 \cdot \left(1- \hat F_n\left(\frac12\right) \right)\right] = \frac  14,
$$
since $\mathsf E\left[\hat F_n(t)\right] = t$.

On the other hand, it is well known that 
$$
\hat F_n(t) \approx t + \frac1{\sqrt{n}}B_t^0,
$$
where $B^0$ is the standard Brownian bridge on $[0,1]$. So
$$
M_n\lesssim \mathsf E\left[\max_{t\in[0,1]} \big\{t (1- t )\big\} +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\max_{t\in[0,1]} \{-t B_t^0\} \right] = \frac  14 + O\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right).
$$

Comment: Could you maybe give a reference for your "well known" formula? It's certainly not well known to me...

Comment: @pi66, see [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function#Asymptotic_properties), the paragraph starting with "This result is extended".

Comment: Thanks. This formula is very important in the calculation. I wonder what happens if we modify the question slightly, as linked to in my edit. Looks like the formula doesn't help anymore.